# Twig - How to check if variable is a number / integer

Tags: php, types, twig, symfony

How to check if variable is a number, integer or float? I can't find anything about this. Making project in Symfony 3.

Comment: If it needs to be an int, why aren't you verifying that before handing it to the view?

Comment: The point is that It's not always an int. That's why I must do it like that.

Comment: That makes more sense :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just add a new [*test*](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#tests)? It keeps your templates readable and is reusable.

Comment: @Yoshi Could be. I'm just a beginner in Twig for now :/.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

At last found something. One of the answers from:
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/932/how-to-check-variable-type

```twig
{# Match integer #}
{% if var matches '/^\\d+$/' %}
{% endif %}

{# Match floating point number #}
{% if var matches '/^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$/' %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you, nice and easy simple solution <3

Comment: This answer is ok if you need a pure Twig solution, but creating an extension is the recommended method in the documentation for both Twig and Symfony. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52946699/1440932

Answer (score 11):

You can create a twig extension to add a test "numeric"

With that, you'll be able to write :

```
{% if foo is numeric %}...{% endif %}
```

Create your extension class :

```
namespace MyNamespace;
class MyTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_twig_extension';
    }

    public function getTests()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_Test('numeric', function ($value) { return  is_numeric($value); }),
        ];
    }
}
```

And in your configuration :

```
services:
    my_twig_extension:
        autowire: true
        class: AppBundle\MyNamespace\MyTwigExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

See documentation :

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#tests

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html